# Unfollowed or non followed?

Tags: word-choice

What is the opposite of a followed link?

Is it an *unfollowed* link (Google says spelling error) or non followed link (sounds clumsy - possibly needs a hyphen)?

Comment: Quite apart from what to call it, what _is_ the opposite of a followed link? I assume you’re talking about HTTP/HTML, and ‘followed link’ means ‘a link that a user has clicked on to be directed to its destination URI’? So are you looking for a word for any link that a user has not (yet?) clicked on? Or for a link that a user clicked on, but then in whatever way did not follow (i.e., hit the ‘stop loading page’ button, went back in the browser history, etc., before the destination URI was loaded)? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Just any non-clicked-on link

Comment: Perhaps a "virgin link" (making a natural analogy between mouse clicking and sexual intercourse).

Comment: @Greg Lee - and one who is a prolific "clicker" of links? I dare ya.

Comment: @LittleEva A Mousanova?

Answer (score 4):

**A link is an “access” point and, therefore, “*unaccessed links*” should be an appropriate term.**

> **unaccessed** *verb*: past tense: accessed; past participle: accessed
>
> **2**. Computing
>
> obtain, examine, or retrieve (data or a file).
>
> *synonyms*: retrieve, gain access to, obtain; read; "the program is used to *access* data" see, Google [**unaccessed**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=unaccessed+&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=accessed+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0i10l5.0.0.0.11150714...........0.oE71LgMymKw&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> See also, Google Books [**Encyclopedia of Human Computer Interaction**](https://books.google.com/books?id=h9iZh_I1YREC&pg=PA185&dq=%22unaccessed+links%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9OMOVczgL4vCggStmoSAAQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22unaccessed%20links%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to refer to links the user did not click on, then you can simply say **unclicked links**. If you do a google search for "unfollowed link", you'll also see a fair amount of sites that use the term **unvisited link**, so this is another possible term.

Comment: To me, "unclicked" is unsatisfactory because clicking is only one example of a user interface for following a link. If a user just "taps" to follow the link on a phone, it is clear that the link has been "tapped" for that user, but it is probably still "unclicked" for that user, right?

So, I think "unvisited" is best.

Comment: @Atsby Tapping a link on a touchscreen triggers the browser’s `click` event to fire, so to the browser, a tapped link _has_ been clicked. On the other hand, a link that is clicked with immediate cancelling of the redirection to the target destination (whether by the user or the site) will have been clicked, but not visited.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That event ought not be called `click` either, it is a misnomer. The event should've been called `visit` or `follow`.